# How to use variable in if body without dropping it after in Rust?

Tags: multithreading, if-statement, rust, scope

I'm initializing a struct which then returns a result to a variable, I then want to start a thread on this variable if the result is Ok without afterwards dropping it as that also drops and stops the thread.

```
let tcp_server: Result<TcpServer> = TcpServer::new(
    settings.server.ip.clone(),
    &settings.http,
    request_handler.clone(),
);
if tcp_server.is_ok() {
    tcp_server.unwrap().start_thread();
    // tcp_server is dropped here
}

IpcListener::new().listen_block();  // Block the main thread

// I want it to be dropped here
```

Is there any way to start the thread on the result wrapped tcp_server only if the result is ok without changing its scope or what alternatives would there be?

Comment: You should probably propagate error that can occur in the `TcpServer::new` earlier and directly use `TcpServer`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. In particular how is `start_thread` defined? In theory there is no reason why dropping `tcp_server` should stop the thread…

Comment: The code you shared most certainly isn't your actual code. `tcp_server` has type `Result<TcpServer`. If `Result` is an instance of Rust's normal `Result` type, it does not have a `start_thread()` method. Also note that there is not reason why `tcp_server` should be dropped at the end of the `if` statement. It's possible that `start_thread()` moves `tcp_server`, but then that would happen regardless of how you call it. The `if` statement does not move `tcp_server`, and if `start_server()` does not consume it, it lives on until the end of the outer scope.

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to post the actual code as its about 700 lines with the `TcpServer` struct being pretty large. I did modify to unwrapping before calling the start thread but replace `TcpServer` with another type and the problem is still there. `start_thread` simple spawns a thread and assigns it to a `handle` member.

Comment: It doesn't matter so much what `start_thread` actually does, but how it's defined, i.e. the signature.

Comment: It takes a mutable reference to self, i.e. `pub fn start_thread(&mut self) { /* code */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is clearly incomplete since it can't possibly work. However, if you want to keep something that may or may not exist past the end of a conditional statement you can use an `Option`:

```rs
let _server = if let Ok(tcp_server) = tcp_server { // use if let to replace unwrap
    tcp_server.start_thread();
    // tcp_server is dropped here
    Some(tcp_server)
} else { None }

IpcListener::new().listen_block();
```

The `tcp_server` will be dropped only if `_server` is dropped. If the server never existed then the option will be `None` and nothing will be dropped when `_server` is dropped.

Comment: Thank you, this solution is probably the best method. But is it required for to pass the variable back out of the if body's scope or would there be any way to do it use the `tcp_server` variable in an if body without moving it into that body?

Comment: Using it in a `if` body will never move it into the body

Comment: But how come the variable is dropped in the `if` body if it's never moved into it? Doesn't your solution simply move it into the `if` body and then move it back out to the `_server` variable?

Comment: @mes3n Possibly the `start_thread` method moves the `tcp_server` if it takes `self` as an argument instead of `&self`.

Comment: @cafce25 Unwrap was missing from the question when posted

Comment: My bad, I should have checked again. regardless the post has now been edited to properly deal with the unwrap.

Comment: @mes3n Do you really want to just ignore the error if `TcpServer::new()` fails? This seems rather strange.

Comment: @SvenMarnach That's what the original code does

Comment: Yeah, sure it is, which is why I addressed my question to the OP, not you. :) It's just a very unsual thing to initialize a TCP server, and to just carry on as if nothing happened if it failed.

Comment: The original problem just goes away if the OP uses `let tcp_server = TcpServer::new(...)?`, which may be what they actually want.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I also have a tls server started the same way and I want to start them even if the other fails, although it might not be practical now that I think about it.

Comment: @mes3n If you really want to ignore the error, you can use `tcp_server.as_ref().map(TcpServer::start_thread);`, which avoids all the `Option` stuff and moving the variable into and out of the if expression.

Comment: (You may want to add `.ok()` or similar to avoid the warning that you must use the result.)

Comment: Why make an `Option`? You can just do `if let Ok(tcp_server) = &mut tcp_server { tcp_server.start_thread(); }`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Or just `tcp_server.as_mut().map(TcpServer::start_thread);`, which does essentially the same thing.